# Suspendable with Nullable

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrofit, okhttp

I need to make the suspendable function **Nullable**. The expected behavior is, when I call the function, If it's an error body, It should simply return `null` rather than throwing `HttpException`.

```kotlin
@GET("product")
suspend fun getProduct(): Product?
```

Is it possible? If yes, how can I do that?

Comment: I do not think Retrofit can do that. It would be the responsibility of the caller of `getProduct()` to catch the exception. That caller might then return `null`, in addition to logging the exception.

Comment: So you're saying that I should create a custom call adapter to support nullability. right? @CommonsWare

Comment: Um, I can't rule that out, but that is not what I was saying. Let's suppose that your Retrofit interface from the question is called `StuffNetworkDataSource`. It would have `getProduct()` that returns `Product` or throws an exception, as is the norm with Retrofit. The `StuffRepository` that uses `StuffNetworkDataSource` calls `getProduct()` and catches the exception. Let's suppose that `StuffRepository` has its own `getProduct()` function that it exposes. *That* `getProduct()` could return `Product?`, with `StuffRepository` returning `null` if Retrofit throws an exception.

Comment: IOW, rather than saying "let's have Retrofit ignore all exceptions", you have another layer in the architecture handle business rules for dealing with those exceptions, including what that layer exposes to the rest of the app in case of an exception.

Comment: Okay. If we go with the first approach (repository handle the error), I'd have to do it for all APIs manually. I just want to know if there's any way that can cover that boilerplate problem with CallAdapter or any retrofit config available.

Comment: I am aware it's not a good practice to completely ignore the exception. but my case is, my android client doesn't want to deal with how the error happened. It simply wants to know if there's data available or not. Whether it's a network error, server error, or even some client input error, it shouldn't care about that. That's my requirement.

Comment: I can't rule out you creating some form of `CallAdapter` that can do what you want. I am not aware of an existing one that does what you want, though.

Comment: It's okay. Thanks for responding. I really appreciate

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218597/discussion-between-theapache64-and-commonsware).